# Android :webview make make urls clickable even data contain clcikable and non clickable urls

Tags: android

How can I make non click-able urls in webview as click-able if the html data contains boths urls in  tag and without  tag. There is one way to first make only click-able urls as non click-able using java script(pattern matching) then making all non click-able urls as click-able urls using java script(pattern matching).